# how to fix "react-native-spinkit:unspecified"

Tags: react-native

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-spinkit'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-spinkit:classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0.
>              Required by:
>                  Myproject:react-native-spinkit:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0/gradle-2.0.0.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0/gradle-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forb
>   idden

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the version not supported `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3`.

You can try two thing here -

1)  upgrade the versions to latest and try to build again.

2)  Try to change version as given below to check if its working with version `2.0.0` or not

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

with

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`.

Hope it solves your problem !